# How to filter two words from different array

Tags: java, android, filtering

I have a custom filter.

```
public void filter(String filter) {
        Restau.clear();
        if (filter != null && filter.trim().length() > 0) {
            for (restauInfoDB element : tempRestList) {
                if ( element.getOh().toLowerCase().contains(filter) ||element.getCost().toLowerCase().contains(filter) ||  element.getResname().toLowerCase().contains(filter) || element.getType().toLowerCase().contains(filter) || element.getResloc().toLowerCase().contains(filter))
                    Restau.add(element);
            }
        } else {
            Restau.addAll(tempRestList);
        }
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

That custom filter only filters from one element. For example i search "Burger" it will only filter only in one element. I want to filter 2 words or more for example
"Burger Samsung" I want to filter every element that has "burger" and "samsung"

`Restau.add(element);`
is the code of my filtered list in CustomListView

Comment: if you want your filter method to be able to filter by multiple words, then you should probably change it sp that you can pass more than one String to that method. `public void filter(String... filter)`

Comment: @911DidBush what do you mean pass more than one string ???

Comment: @Lemme You want to your filter method to be able to filter by multiple words, but it only accepts one string as an argument. It would make much more sense if it would accept multiple strings aka words. That way you wouldn't have to split the filter string inside the method. Or is the filter method an overridden method and you cannot change the signature?

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following, using lists:

```
public void filter(List<String> filters) {
    Restau.clear();
    if (!filters.isEmpty())
    {
        for (restauInfoDB element : tempRestList) {
            // Stuff the content into an array
            List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            contents.add(element.getOh().toLowerCase());
            contents.add(element.getCost().toLowerCase());
            etc...

            boolean matchAll = true;
            for(String filter : filters) {
                boolean matchFilter = false;
                for(String content : contents) {
                    if (content.contains(filter)) {
                        matchFilter = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // If this filter was not found, then set matchAll to false
                if (!matchFilter) {
                    matchAll = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (matchAll)
                Restau.add(element);
        }
    } else {
        Restau.addAll(tempRestList);
    }
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: i'm getting error when calling the `adapter.filter(text);` cannot be applied to `(java.lang.String)`

Comment: Well, that's because this version accepts a list of strings.  You could change it to accept an array of strings, instead, or do what @911DidBush suggested with a vararg parameter, "String... filter"

Comment: sorry for being a newbie but. what particular code should I change ?